# Reference shell Script within a shell Script in YAML

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script, kubernetes

Is there the right way to reference a shell script written within a script in a YAML file. For eg:

```
    data:
        ex1.sh: |
        #!/bin/bash -x
        . /shellscriptloc/ex2.sh
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ex2.sh: |
        <no bin bash>
```

**The YAML file is part of a helm chart setup that is triggered during helm install and helm hooks**

**The YAML file is imported into a daemon set, and the yaml file presented as a config. in the daemon set, the script is called to execute inside a Kubernetes node. And the script is passed as data from this YAML file**

q1 : is the location reference of ex2.sh correct for using/calling methods defined within ex2.sh :-       **. /shellscriptloc/ex2.sh** this is the current way I tried but causing errors.
q2 : does not defining ex2.sh as bin bash, the right way to go about it? ex2.sh contains functions that can be called are used within ex1.sh

Thanks in advance